# How I can start Selenium in current Window of Firefox? Without opening new window

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver, new-window

I need to start my JAVA Selenium code in current Window of Firefox. But when I start my code `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` will open new window! Don't need open new window!
In Selenium IDE code works in current window of browser.

```
package tm.csgo;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Item {

public String siteUrl;
public String url;
public String name;
public int bought;
public int needCount;
public int wantPrice;
public double price;

public void buyProcess() {

    System.out.println("Начало покупки, запуск браузера...");
    System.out.println("Запланировано приобрести " + needCount + " " + name + " предметов.");

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


    while(bought <= needCount){

        System.out.println("Приобретаем " + bought + " предмет");
        driver.get(siteUrl + url);
        price = Double.parseDouble(driver.findElement(By.className("ip-bestprice")).getText());

        System.out.println("Стоимость предмета " + name + ": " + price + " рублей");

        if (price <= wantPrice) {

            System.out.println("Покупаем " + name + "...");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.buy-pic-button")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("info_dialog_url")).click();

        } else {
            continue;
            }

        System.out.println("Приобретён " + bought + " предмет за " + price + " рублей из " + needCount + " запланированных предметов");
        bought++;
    }

}

public void purchaseReady() {
    //дописать общую сумму затрат
    System.out.println("Приобретено предметов на сумму ...");
    System.out.println("Покупка успешно завершена!");
}
```

}

Comment: What version of Selenium are you using?  This is possible with both WebDriver and Selenium2.  Not sure about other versions though.

Comment: Last versions of Selenium and Java.

Comment: 2.53 is it possible?

Comment: You are likely calling `driver.quit()` then.  You should post your code so we can look it over.

Comment: my code is simple. I start with it: `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`And next I need use site, but site should have cookies for use it. But I can't log in in every code, because site: http://steamcommunity.com/ Where for log in I should use mobile steam guard...

Comment: Like I mentioned above, are you calling `driver.quit();`?  Are you using any annotations like `@BeforeMethod` or `@AfterMethod`?  Calling `.quit()` will kill the instance of the browser.

Comment: If I use `driver.quit();` I have an error: `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: The FirefoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called.`. I added my code in main question. Please tell me know, where I should use `driver.quit();` and how?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using Selenium with junit for running separate tests. 
Here is basically the architecture:

1. I have a singleton Context class that creates instance of Selenium WebDriver, depending on the browser. As part of the implementation I am checking if `webDriver = null;`. For the browser `if (browser == Browser.IE)` and etc. Here is the code that returns WebDriver instance:

   ```
   public WebDriver getWebDriver() {
       if (webDriver != null) {
           return webDriver;
       }
   }
   ```
2. I have a base test class that instantiates the Context one. In @Before I have a setup method for browser starting:

   ```
   @Before
   public final void setUp() {
       startBrowser();
   }
   ```

   Here is the startBrowser method:

   ```
   private void startBrowser() {
       context.getWebDriver().get("about:blank"); 
   }
   ```
3. As part of the basic test class I have also @AfterClass annotation that quits the browser:

   ```
   @AfterClass
   public static void tearDownClass() {
       Context.getSingleton().quit();
   }
   ```
4. The last steps is to include all @Test annotations between @Before and @AfterClass ones. All of them will be executed without browser restarting. 
   If you decide to develop this framework further I would suggest you to create another class that extends the test one and which contains only the tests (all @Test methods). Also in my case I am using the PageObject pattern. All this will help you for a better test framework structure and will optimize your code in case  of changes.

Hope this help you!